# How do I connect the wire from my outside mobile home pole box to the wire on the little shed that I just moved to my property

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker

How do I connect the wire I have extra laying around from my mobile home pole breaker box to the new shed I recently had moved next to the trailer. The wires are already ran throughout the shed with only a wire hanging out of the bottom of the shed. I have some 12 2 wire that I want to use to connect the already existing wire in the shed to my breaker box on my pole next to the mobile home. How can I connect them?

Comment: Probably need different cable as 12 2 usually refers to nm cable designed for  the indoor use. In any case need to see pictures of the breaker panel.